# how to show UIMenuController to UIBarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to show `UIMenuController` under `UIBarButtonItem` when click it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assume your UIBarButtonItem has been connected to:

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(UIBarButtonItem*)sender event:(UIEvent*)event;
```

Then paste these codes into your view controller:

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(UIBarButtonItem*)sender event:(UIEvent*)event{
    [self becomeFirstResponder];

    /*get the view from the UIBarButtonItem*/
    UIView *buttonView=[[event.allTouches anyObject] view];
    CGRect buttonFrame=[buttonView convertRect:buttonView.frame toView:self.view];

    UIMenuController *menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
    UIMenuItem *resetMenuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Menu Item" action:@selector(menuItemClicked:)];

    NSAssert([self becomeFirstResponder], @"Sorry, UIMenuController will not work with %@ since it cannot become first responder", self);
    [menuController setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:resetMenuItem]];
    [menuController setTargetRect:buttonFrame inView:self.view];
    [menuController setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];

    [resetMenuItem release];
}
- (void) copy:(id) sender {
    // called when copy clicked in menu
}
- (void) menuItemClicked:(id) sender {
    // called when Item clicked in menu
}
- (BOOL) canPerformAction:(SEL)selector withSender:(id) sender {
    if (selector == @selector(menuItemClicked:) /*|| selector == @selector(copy:)*/ /*<--enable that if you want the copy item */) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
- (BOOL) canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}
```

The key is to return YES for canBecomeFirstResponder and canPerformAction.

[Here](http://d.pr/1ZwF)'s the sample project if you need it.

These codes are actually come from other posts in stackoverflow, I just combined them.

[Figure out UIBarButtonItem frame in window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994354/figure-out-uibarbuttonitem-frame-in-window)

[How to get UIMenuController work for a custom view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146587/how-to-get-uimenucontroller-work-for-a-custom-view)

Comment: I found the positioning of the menu was sometimes too far to the right when trying this myself.  I was able to fix it by changing the lines:  
`CGRect buttonFrame=[buttonView convertRect:buttonView.frame toView:self.view];`  
and `[menuController setTargetRect:buttonFrame inView:self.view];`  

to:  
`[menuController setTargetRect:buttonView.frame inView:buttonView.superview];`
gave more accurate positions.