# UIPopover in ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I would like to create something like this:
[image]

The copy, star, reply, details. Is this just a UIPopover with a segmented button on it?

Here's another example of what I want:
[image]

Anyone got something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class you are looking for is `UIMenuController`

[This SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146587/how-to-get-uimenucontroller-work-for-a-custom-view) has a lot of useful information.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Ive been trying to recreate that view with a UIPopoverViewcontroller, holding a UIViewController with a UISegment.. and Im not getting that same functionality.  The main issue is the UIPopoverVC is giving me a 3d border around my viewcontroller/view.

It does appear that its a custom view.  Which, on that note, would not be too difficult to create by the way, and that view can host your SegmentedViewController, just not in a UIPopoverVC.

And.. for your viewing enjoyment... here is the code that creates the CGPath for a "Balloon" view like the Popover creates.  this code goes in your drawRect.

```
    float radius=5; //corner radius
    CGContextSaveGState(context);


    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, backColor.red,backColor.green,backColor.blue,backColor.alpha);


    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, CGRectGetMinX(rect) + radius, CGRectGetMinY(rect));
    CGContextAddArc(context, CGRectGetMaxX(rect) - radius, CGRectGetMinY(rect) + radius, radius, 3 * M_PI / 2, 0, 0);
    CGContextAddArc(context, CGRectGetMaxX(rect) - radius, CGRectGetMaxY(rect) - radius, radius, 0, M_PI / 2, 0);
    CGContextAddArc(context, CGRectGetMinX(rect) + radius, CGRectGetMaxY(rect) - radius, radius, M_PI / 2, M_PI, 0);
    CGContextAddArc(context, CGRectGetMinX(rect) + radius, CGRectGetMinY(rect) + radius, radius, M_PI, 3 * M_PI / 2, 0);    

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, rect.size.width/2, rect.size.height);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, rect.size.width/2, rect.size.height+10);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, rect.size.width/2+10, rect.size.height);

    CGContextClosePath(context);

    CGContextFillPath(context);

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

Comment: hmm...got confused here, so what did you use in the end?

Comment: sorry... to get the exact experience.. create your own view, have that view draw itself in what I call the "Balloon View", I added code above that creates the path for that view.  You will still need to style that view.   Have your Balloon view host a UISegmentedView.   Then, just pop open the Balloon view on your own, without using the Popover VIew Controller.

Comment: so you're suggesting not to use the popupviewcontroller, then how do you show it? how do you pop open the Ballon view on your own? an example would help