# iPhone iOS how to paste image into a UIImageView with long press

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimage, uipasteboard

I got a general idea that I can use a `UIPasteBoard` to control the copy/paste contents. I would like to allow the user to long press on an image and overwrite that image with the paste board contents.

What concerns me is how to do this in a user-friendly way. I do not know how to present the Apple-style "copy/paste" callout for a UIImageView. Are there any examples of how this is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class you are looking for is UIMenuController. It will let you display a standard copy/paste menu from any view.

This question has more info: [How to get UIMenuController work for a custom view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146587/how-to-get-uimenucontroller-work-for-a-custom-view)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I've been looking for!