# How to enable UITextView to receive pasted images

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview, uimenucontroller

I need to support pasting of images into a `UITextView`. With an image copied to the clipboard, the "`Paste`" option doesn't seem to pop up. It does when there's text on the clipboard.

This is how to override the `paste` option in a custom `UITextView`. But I need help on how to get the option to show up to begin with...

```
// This gets called when user presses menu "Paste" option
- (void)paste:(id)sender{

    UIImage *image = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].image;

    if (image) {
        NSTextAttachment *textAttachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
        textAttachment.image = image;
        NSAttributedString *imageString = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:textAttachment];
        self.attributedText = imageString;
    } else {
        // Call the normal paste action
        [super paste:sender];
    }
}
```

I came across a few related questions, but they weren't helpful for an inexperienced developer like myself:
[How to get UIMenuController work for a custom view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146587/how-to-get-uimenucontroller-work-for-a-custom-view), [How to paste image from pasteboard on UITextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29175089/how-to-paste-image-from-pasteboard-on-uitextview)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I answered my own question. All you have to do is have the UITextView say "I can receive pasted images" by overriding this UITextView method:

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    if (action == @selector(paste:) && [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].image)
        return YES;
    else
        return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

You're welcome.

Comment: Your code is correct, but my paste option is not coming after i copy an image . How to resolve this ?

Comment: Did you remember to set the UITextView to be an instance of the custom class you created with this code?

Comment: @MattKoala Thanks your answer is perfect.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @Matt your answer helped me. Just extending your answer which may help some one,

Subclassing UITextview, which shows paste option on long press when you have image in pasteboard.

```
class MyTextView:UITextView {
    var onPasteImage:(()->Void)?
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if action == #selector(paste(_:)) && UIPasteboard.general.image != nil {
            return true
        }else{
            return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
        }
    }
    
    override func paste(_ sender: Any?) {
        super.paste(sender)
        if UIPasteboard.general.image != nil {
            onPasteImage?()
        }
    }
}
```

And wait for `onPasteImage` closure to be called on tap paste in textview,

```
inputFieldForReply.textView.onPasteImage = { [weak self] in
    if let image = UIPasteboard.general.image {
        // Process pasted image
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! but where do you concatenate the imge with the rest of the text in the UITEXTVIEW?

Comment: i don't think so we can insert image in the same textview, Refer WhatsApp for the behaviour!. When an image is pasted from clipboard we can show a new screen with pasted image and a textview at bottom which contain user typed text.